# Trying to make a function return two values using pointers but I'm getting the error: expected an identifier

Tags: c, function, pointers

It's supposed to be function that returns two  random numbers depending on a range chosen by the user, I read I could use pointers to return two values from a function  but I get the error `expected an identifier` right before `int* ran1` and `int* ran2`and when I run the code I get the error  `expected ')' before 'int'` Both `ran1` and `ran2` are global variables. Even when I use different names for the pointers I still get the same error.

```
int level(lev, ran1, ran2, int* ran1, int* ran2){
    srand(time(0));
    if(lev == 'l'){
            ran1=(rand()%10+1);
            ran2=(rand()%10+1);
    }
    if(lev == 'm'){
        ran1=(rand()%50+11);
        ran2=(rand()%50+11);
    }
    if(lev == 'h'){
        ran1=(rand()%100+51);
        ran2=(rand()%100+51);
    }
}
```

Comment: your function prototype is... bad. All your arguments should have types (and your compiler will definitely complain about that). You **cannot** have the same parameter name twice. So your compiler will tell you this is illegal.

Comment: Your random number seed generation is ... bad. Using `time(0)` as a seed is a typical beginners mistake from a time where it was unlikely the same thing was started within the same second (so, 1972, not later). *Don't* do that, you will have pain later.

Comment: Your assignment to the pointers is not what you mean to do. Sorry, that's not how you use pointers! You want to go back to your C book and read about that. This is really too broad to be compactly answered sufficiently – you're making multiple basic mistakes in a short snippet of code, indicating what you need is a good systematic introduction to C, not a singular answer! I think you're quite smart, but you've been approaching things too "isolatedly".

Comment: `ran1=(rand()%10+1);` ==> `*ran1=(rand()%10+1);` Also, move the `srand` to the beginning of `main` and comment it out while debugging. I don't have an issure with seeding with the time - it is extremely rare for me to run the same program twice within the same second. If you want a seriously random input, you won't be using `srand` and `rand` anyway.

Comment: @MarcusMüller both `ran1` and `ran2` are global variables so I didn't see a need to redeclare their data types. I just named the pointers  `ran1` and `ran2` since it's convenient even when I change their names I get the same errors

Comment: They are not global variables in the posted code, but (duplicated) function arguments. *I didn't see a need to redeclare their data types* this is a matter of C syntax, what you see a need for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I get the error expected an identifier right before int* ran1 and int* ran2"*

The C compiler error message phrase *"expected an identifier"* is seen for many syntactical errors, across a wide variety of compilers (even for other languages)  In this case the compiler is squawking about following *typed* variables with *untyped* variables.  This

```
int level(lev, ran1, ran2, int* ran1, int* ran2){
          ^^^ untyped ^^^  ^^^^ typed ^^^^^^^^^
```

Although rarely used today this antiquated syntax, when accepted by some C compilers, is to provide backward compatibility with older versions of the C language.  Silence the compiler by surrounding the *untyped* with parenthesis:

```
int level((lev), int* ran1, int* ran2){
```

*(Note `ran1` and `ran2`, removed.  Even if somehow legal in positions 2 & 3 would result in multiple definition of the same variables in position 4 & 5)*

An aside, not all of the parameters are necessary to accomplish what your code example is doing.   The code below shows removes those that are not needed.

Note, when passing a `int` pointer  to be updated, its value needs to be updated, which in this case will be `*ran1` or `*ran2`, not `ran1` or `ran2`.

(the `*` symbol when used in this context *de-references* a pointer, and in this example, the de-referenced pointer is the value to be updated.)

Also, as pointed out in comments, [srand()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_srand.htm) needs only to be called once during a program session, and should be seeded such that if the program has a short run-time duration, and may be called in quick succession, will have a unique seed value for each call.

The following illustrates these corrections in your code:

```
int level(int lev, int *ran1, int *ran2){//removed unused parameters
    //srand(clock());//moved to main, so just called once
    if(lev == 'l'){
            *ran1=(rand()%10+1);//Updating value *ran1 not pointer ran1 (apply to all)
            *ran2=(rand()%10+1);
    }
    if(lev == 'm'){
        *ran1=(rand()%50+11);
        *ran2=(rand()%50+11);
    }
    if(lev == 'h'){
        *ran1=(rand()%100+51);
        *ran2=(rand()%100+51);
    }
    return 0;//prototype requires a return statement
             //alternatively, the prototype can be made void
             //as 'level(...)' returns its work via its parameters.
}

int main(void)
{
    //calling this only once per execution, 
    srand(GetTickCount());//number of milliseconds elapsed since system started,
    
    int lev = 1, ran1, ran2;
    
    level(lev, &ran1, &ran2);
    
    return 0;//int main(void) requires a return statement
}
```

Comment: I would recommend moving `srand` to the start of `main`, but not to seed it from `clock()` (which is likely to return `0` at that point) but from `time()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane - good idea.

Comment: hey, this is C, so `lev` doesn't *actually need* a type qualifier – it defaults to int; `void foo(a,b) {}` is perfectly legal C. However, this is *extremely* bad style, an idea of the 1970s, and in any compiler I've personally ever used will lead to a warning. However, what **is** illegal is to have a typed argument after untyped arguments. That can't work. The compiler complains about the `int` in the argument list; there should have been an `)`, because that's the only thing that can follow a sequence of untyped arguments.

Comment: in any case, the problem here really is that the asker has a few fundamental problems with C syntax, and what scope is and so on. I think your answer is good!

Comment: @Marcus - Great distinction - I have edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: The K&R variant would be: `int level(lev, ran1, ran2) int *ran1,*ran2; {`), not what you wrote.

Comment: @MarcusMüller " it defaults to int" --> Does that apply to C11, C17 or just some  outdated versions of C?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it's legal in all revisions of C. You can try with the C compiler of your choice. They will warn, but not refuse, even in strictest of modes.

Comment: @PSkocik yep, that way you'd also get `ran1` and `ran2` to be typed (as `int` pointers). The only thing that's illegal is mixing these. You can't have `int level(lev, int *ran1, int *ran2)`, either.

Comment: @ryyker `int level((lev, ran1, ran2), int* ran1, int* ran2){` is a (irrecoverable) syntax error in all C compilers I have installed. AFAIK, such C syntax never was supported anywhere.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hmmm, WIth `gcc -std=c11 -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.c"` I get error: `../main.c:7:11: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token` `7 | int level((lev, ran1, ran2), int* ran1, int* ran2){"`.  What compiler/version are you using?

Comment: @PSkocik - That line was an unfortunate typo.   I had used something entirely different when testing with my compiler (CLANG), and copied an incorrect prototype in.  I have edited to reflect what I have actually tested successfully.  Note with _normal_ and _extended_, I get a clean compile, but with _all_ I get warning: _warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'_  Sorry for delay in response.  Was away from desk for a little while. (and will likely be away again here shortly :))

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that's not my code, that's someone else's code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `echo "void foo(a, b) {}"> test.c; gcc -c -o test test.c` runs through flawlessly, is what I was [said above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69990310/trying-to-make-a-function-return-two-values-using-pointers-but-im-getting-the-e#comment123725428_69990556).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Given the changes to [C2X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x), I suspect the `void foo(a, b) {}` may be disallowed - We shall see.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm not aware of anything like that being in N2731, and honestly, knowing how the C development works, it'd surprise me if they took away formerly legal things like that!